# getenv() returning value for "VAR", but getenv("VAR") returning false

Tags: php, apache

I have defined some environment variables in the Apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public

    SetEnv API_TOKEN xyz
    SetEnv DSN "pgsql:host=x.x.x.x;port=5432;dbname=db;user=user;password=pass"

    <Directory "/var/www/public">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I try to get the value of the `"DSN"` variable in a php page, and it is very strange:

```php
<?php 

var_dump(getenv()); 

echo "TOKEN: " .( getenv('API_TOKEN') ?: "false") .'<br>';
echo "DSN: " . (getenv('DSN') ?: "false") .'<br>';
```

Output:

```php
array(39) {
...
["DSN"]=>
  string(94) "pgsql:host=x.x.x.x;port=5432;dbname=db;user=user;password=pass"
["API_TOKEN"]=>
  string(3) "xyz"
...
}

TOKEN: xyz
DSN: false
```

What can explain that the DSN env var is in the array returned by `getenv()` with no arguments, but not returned by `getenv("DSN")`?

Comment: Not sure but try `var_dump(array_keys(getenv()));`

Comment: Hi @AbraCadaver, well, it outputs ... the keys of the array I get with getenv(). No surprise, "DSN" is here. What should I be searching?

Comment: Is it length 3?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: yes; `[31]=> string(3) "DSN"`

Comment: Try next construction `var_dump(getenv()["DSN"]); `

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev tanks, that's finally what I've done, but I don't like not understanding what is going on...